# ¿Cómo funcional el useCallback?

Tags: react-hooks

Entiendo que el **useCallback** memoriza una función y cuando llamamos a la función se ejecuta siempre la misma, es decir, no cambia hasta que sus dependencias lo hagan. Pero acá me surge una duda, ¿por qué el **useState filter** de mi componente cambia con el **setFilter** del **handleFilterChange**, pero si muestro el valor de **filter** dentro del **handleFilterChange** no cambia de su valor preterminado?
¿Acaso mantiene el espacio de memoria de la primera renderización del **filter** pero no del **setFilter**?

```
export const CallbackHook = () => {
    const items = ['hola', 'jorge', 'jhon', 'jaider'];
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState('');

    const handleFilterChange = useCallback((event) => {
        console.log('useCallback', filter)
        setFilter(event.target.value);
    }, []);


    return (
        <>
            <input type="text" value={filter} onChange={handleFilterChange} />
            <ul>
                {filteredItems.map(item => (
                    <li key={item}>{item}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </>
    );
}
```